# Mount a Linux Disk Image with two file systems?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, disk-image, arm

I'm working with the new Kali Linux ARM images, and after hours of not figuring anything out in terms of mounting, I got it to mount via my Mac and fuse. Here's the curious thing, it's a single image that mounts one msdos partition (vfat) and one ext4 partition. With that, I can't mount on my linux machine with the usual

> mount -o loop -t ext4

As it's two file systems, it fails.

What would be the correct command to mount one image (.img) which contains both of those filesystems in two partitions?

Comment: I guess it's not a disk or partition image, but actually a raw disk dump. You have to write it to a drive (for example using `dd`).

Answer (score 0):

You can mount it by specifying the appropriate offset that the filesystem starts at using the `offset` mount option. I am not entirely sure how to find the offset just by looking at the image though.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. I think my route will be to let macfuse auto mount, then I'll just copy onto an EXT4 formatted image and see if that works. Yes? I don't need boot info as I'm going to chroot.